# Toggle classes in different components in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Let's say I created a plugin in my Nuxt app:

```
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/toggler',
  ],
```

which contains:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggler() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    },
  },
})
```

I would like to toggle classes on elements on different components, like:

```
<div :class="{ 'is-active': isActive }"></div>
```

and it's correctly triggered via a button:

```
    <button @click.prevent="toggler" />
```

However, this only change the class on other elements inside the same .vue component where the button is.

Other elements with the same `:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }"` in different .vue components aren't affected, unless I add a button in those components too.

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-http-fqlx5

Comment: Can you show how you're using this mixin?

Comment: You're missing that component state is local. How these components are related? The question doesn't even mention it. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: I added it in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-http-fqlx5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you create a mixin in a plugin?

**Create and usage mixin:**

**create:**

In the mixins folder inside You're creating a mixin file (example.js)

**usage:**

import into the component:

```
import example from '~/mixins/example'
```

Mixin definition into component into script:

```
export default {
  mixins: [example],
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {}
}
```

This allows it to be reused into any component.